# How to Overlay Text in Premiere Pro or After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, premiere

I am a newbie to both Premiere Pro and After Effects.  We are making exercise instructional videos and want to overlay text instructions - very much like this video:

.

What would be the recommended way to do this. We have both Premiere Pro and After Effects.

Thanks for any assistance/tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Premiere Pro** have more basic text tools, but it is easier to work with. Also, it is better for long files.

**After Effects** allows you to manipulate with your text in much more various ways. You can use there more different text effects. But it is also more complicated.

So, it is up to you to decide. If you are looking for something basic, use Premiere. If you want to use some fancy effects, then use After Effects.

For example typewriter effect, which is used in video in your question is one of the standard AE effects. You can also [achieve that with Premiere Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s6mbBnaO-DU), but you will spend more time on each text.

Comment: Shultc, thank you for the tip. So what I've done is created the basic video in Premier Pro (it was relatively easy).  My partner created the intro and outro in AE.  So now, I guess what I need to to is to bring in my exercise video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-VUMfF45Azo) into AE, do my text overlay and loop the video if I need more time. Thanks! Your tip was very helpful!

Comment: If you want to use both programs you can use dynamic links 
https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/dynamic-link-effects.html

Answer (score 1):

I place [text overlays](https://youtu.be/saIUJeDWql4?t=8s) in my Premiere Pro videos several times a week. (I produce a video every day.) Premiere Pro has a "Title" menu with many options:

[image]

Once you create a Default Still, Default Roll, or Default Crawl, you can drag it onto your timeline, size it, change the duration of it, and even animate it if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished both in Adobe Premiere and After Effects just like Shultc said.

You can start and use the After Effects Preset(default text effects) as you go along and start to use more advance effects and animation such as lower thirds, text reveal etc...

[How to access and use adobe presets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=24&v=SRnepJMsd98)

[image]

What I usually do is to create a templates for different overlay text effects in after effects so whenever I want to use those specific effects I will just open that file and drag the video.

Same goes for intro and outro were in this allows you to save more time from creating the effect again from scratch.